# .htaccess redirect to root to link not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Think my domain is `www.example.com`, I want to redirect visitor to `www.example.com/main-page` . To do that I have written this **.htaccess** code but its doesn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$/ /main-page/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Could any one please help me, I can't find the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect just the home page you will need this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /main-page [L,R=301]
```

If you don't want URL to change then use:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /main-page [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be just

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main-page [L]
```

Or with the  [R] flag to force redirect :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main-page [R]
```

Comment: Have you verified this rule?